# Enabling scrolling for particular layout

Tags: android

I have facing problem in scrolling webview in verticlly, actually i have scroll view with in the layout have defined webview in layout so when i scroll the webview vertically it scroll whole layout,so i want to enable scroll for webview,
anybody help me solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the scrollbars to your webview then, no need to put a surrounding scrollView.

```
android:scrollbars="vertical"
```

and other android:scroll* attributes are available for the webview.
Wondering though why the webview doesn't scroll by default in your case, it should. Just removing the surrounding scrollView around it might already help probably.